# use viewContainerRef in MdDialog config angular material 2

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material2, angular-components, mddialog

I'm working on project where we need a base / custom template for the modal dialog. For example, the header section, footer and the content area will be a part of a component(say ModalComponent). I've to load the content dynamically inside the content area.
The ModalComponent will be passed as an input to dialog.open()

```
<div class="header">
  <h2 md-dialog-title>Delete all</h2>
</div>
<md-dialog-content #dynamic>Dialog Content</md-dialog-content>
<md-dialog-actions>
...
</md-dialog-actions>
```

will viewContainerRef help in such a way to define a custom template for the modal.